# Trying to Encrypt and decrypt a text file (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-handling

This program is trying to encrypt a text file. It contains a dictionary of different symbols and their corresponding codes. The problem is with the whitespace, it's not supposed to convert it to anything so it should just leave the space like that but the program doesn't read the whitespace.

```
codes = {
    "A": "%",
    "a": "9",

"B": "@",
"b": "3",

"C": "!",
"c": "1",

"D": "$",
"d": "8",

"E": "^",
"e": "5",

"F": "`",
"f": "4",

"G": "7",
"g": "~",

"H": "(",
"h": "0",

"I": ")",
"i": "2",

"J": "*",
"j": "6",

"K": "-",
"k": "£",

"L": "_",
"l": "¤",

"M": "+",
"m": "¥",

'N': '"',
"n": "¦",

"O": "/",
"o": "§",

"P": "<",
"p": "«",

"Q": ">",
"q": "¬",

"R": "µ",
"r": "{",

"S": "¶",
"s": "}",

"T": "»",
"t": ";",

"U": "|",
"u": "Ø",

"V": "ß",
"v": "=",

"W": "&",
"w": "×",

"X": ",",
"x": "¿",

"Y": ".",
"y": "ä",

"Z": "?",
"z": "¢",
",": "€",
"-": "ð",
".": "Ç",
"1": "ö",
"2": "Д",
"3": "Ж",
"4": "Ђ",
"5": "È",
"6": "À",
"7": "Φ",
"8": "Ψ",
"9": "Ω",
"0": "ö",
" ": " ",
"": ""
}

encrypted = []
read_file = open("file1.txt", "r")

for line in read_file:
    line_list = []
    for ch in line:
        if ch not in codes.keys():
            codes[ch] = str(ch)
            line_list.append(codes[ch.strip()])
        else:
            line_list.append(codes[ch.strip()])
    encrypted.append(line_list)
read_file.close()

write_file = open("new file.txt", "w")
for line in encrypted:
    encrypted_line = "".join(line)
    write_file.write(encrypted_line + "\n")
write_file.close()

read_file = open("new file.txt", "r")

encoded_file = []
for encoded in read_file:
    encoded_list = []
    encoded_list.append(encoded.strip())
    encoded_file.append(encoded_list)
read_file.close()
```

After encrypting this part of the program is supposed to read from the encrypted file and decrypt it and display the result on the screen. But the is no space between the words since it didn't convert in the previous part.

```
read_file = open("new file.txt", "r")

values = list(codes.values())
keys = list(codes.keys())

decrypted_line = ""
for l in encoded_file:
    for l_l in l:
        for ch_l in l_l:
            if ch_l in values:
                index = values.index(ch_l)
                decrypted_line += keys[index]
            # elif ch_l == " ":
            #     decrypted_line += " "

        print(decrypted_line)
        decrypted_line = ""
```

Please help with this spacing problem

Comment: What will happen in `ch.strip()` if `ch` is a space?

Comment: Thanks it works but how do I remove the new line at the end of each line

Comment: @AkinAkinbobola  use `ch.replace("\n", "")` to remove all the newlines. (if ch is your string variable)